# How MVC service works if deployed on Azure?

Tags: azure, model-view-controller

I am writing a MVC application in .NET core and it is intended to go on Azure.
In the application startup, I added a service which reads a file/Db and creates a collection. (This is a heavy task and should not be repeated)
This service will be called by a request and depending on the input and data in the collection, output will be generated.
I added the service using the below code -

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceInterface, ServiceObject>();
```

I expected that it will not call the constructor more than once but it does call the constructor on every request.

This is a problem but the bigger question is -
How do I create a pool of objects which can process the requests in parallel?
Or How do I configure this service to accept multiple requests in parallel?

I assume there should be some attribute that will declare this service to be thread safe

Surely there is some gap in my understanding of how MVC/Azure works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on Azure, this is the kind of thing that should be left to e.g. WebJobs.

The problem with running long-running jobs in the web tier is that they take resources away from handling requests. And what if there is an error? How will you retry?

In Azure, you can do something like this instead:

1. Web tier sends message to Service Bus Queue / Storage Queue
2. Continuous WebJob listening to that queue picks up the message and processes it.

There are a few good sides to this approach:

1. The WebJobs can be put in an entirely different App Service Plan, reducing the workload on the web tier. They can also scale independently.
2. Continuous WebJobs run parallel by default. At least from Service Bus Queues, the SDK picks up 8 messages at a time for processing, and it also runs on every single instance in the App Service Plan, so it can scale.
3. If you get an exception during processing, the message will not be removed from the queue. The WebJob will retry processing it.

Service Bus Queues have the advantage that they can guarantee message ordering and that the messages are only delivered once. Storage Queues are more inexpensive, but don't give these guarantees. You mentioned this task should only run once, so Service Bus would be better for your case. *However*, typically you really do want your WebJobs to be idempotent. So then even if it fails to complete a task, it can safely retry.

You can find samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus/Functions.cs